The "" file does not exist
Symfony version: 6.4
Api platform version: 3.2
PHP version: 8.2
When I try to create a media object, I get this error:
"Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\\Component\\Mime\\Exception\\InvalidArgumentException: \"The \"\" file does not exist or is not readable.\" at FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser.php line 44"  

This is random: sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.
Edit: when I try to add a media object a second time, it works.  What I mean is, I create an activity with a media object the upload fails, but when I modify this activity and add the same media object, it works. On another try, it will work directly on creation.  Only on production. In dev, it works fine.
I added `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to app.prod.ini:
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
post_max_size = 1024M

And I added `fileSize` property to my media class as here: The file "" does not exist (VichUploaderBundle)
Edit 2: I edit php.ini on host machine then in docker container directly via `docker exec -it`  but the result is the same.  I wonder if there isn't a configuration problem in app.prod.ini. I wonder if `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` are taken into account in production.
Here is my Media.php class:
<?php

#[Vich\Uploadable]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: MediaRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new GetCollection(uriTemplate: '/medias.{_format}'),
        new Post(
            uriTemplate: '/medias',
            controller: CreateMediaObject::class,
            openapi: new Operation(
                requestBody: new RequestBody(
                    content: new \ArrayObject([
                        'multipart/form-data' => [
                            'schema' => [
                                'type' => 'object',
                                'properties' => [
                                    'file' => [
                                        'type' => 'string',
                                        'format' => 'binary'
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                    ])
                )
            ),
            validationContext: ['groups' => ['Default', 'media:collection:post']],
            deserialize: false,
            name: 'app_create_media'
        ),
        new Patch(uriTemplate: '/medias/{id}.{_format}'),
        new Get(uriTemplate: '/medias/{id}.{_format}'),
        new Delete(uriTemplate: '/medias/{id}.{_format}'),
    ],
    outputFormats: ['jsonld' => ['application/ld+json']],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['media:collection:get', 'media:item:get']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['media:collection:post', 'media:item:patch']],
    security: "is_granted('ROLE_USER')",
    provider: MediaStateProvider::class
)]
#[ApiFilter(OrderFilter::class,
    properties: ['name']
)]
class Media
{
    use TimestampableEntity;

    private const TYPES = ['PDF', 'Vidéo', 'Audio', 'Image'];

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(['media:collection:get', 'media:item:get'])]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'medias')]
    private ?Activity $activity = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['media:collection:get', 'media:item:get', 'media:collection:post', 'media:item:patch'])]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    #[Assert\Choice(choices: Media::TYPES, message: 'Veuillez choisir un type valide.')]
    #[Groups(['media:collection:get', 'media:item:get', 'media:collection:post', 'media:item:patch'])]
    private ?string $type = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['media:collection:get', 'media:item:get', 'media:collection:post', 'media:item:patch'])]
    public ?string $filePath = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['media:collection:get', 'media:item:get', 'media:collection:post', 'media:item:patch'])]
    public ?int $fileSize = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['media:collection:get', 'media:item:get', 'media:collection:post', 'media:item:patch'])]
    public ?string $mimeType = null;

    #[ApiProperty(types: ['https://schema.org/contentUrl'])]
    #[Groups(['media:collection:get', 'media:item:get'])]
    private ?string $contentUrl = null;

    #[Vich\UploadableField(mapping: 'media_object', fileNameProperty: 'filePath', size: 'fileSize', mimeType: 'mimeType')]
    public ?File $file = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getActivity(): ?Activity
    {
        return $this->activity;
    }

    public function setActivity(?Activity $activity): static
    {
        $this->activity = $activity;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): static
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getType(): ?string
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function setType(string $type): static
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContentUrl(): ?string
    {
        return $this->contentUrl;
    }

    public function setContentUrl(?string $contentUrl): self
    {
        $this->contentUrl = $contentUrl;

        return $this;
    }
}

And my CreateMediaObject.php class:

<?php

#[AsController]
final class CreateMediaObject extends AbstractController
{
    public function __construct(
        ...
    ) {}

    public function __invoke(Request $request): Media
    {
       /** @var UploadedFile $uploadedFile */
        $uploadedFile = $request->files->get('file');
        if (!$uploadedFile) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('"file" is required');
        }

        $type = match ($uploadedFile->getClientOriginalExtension()) {
            'mp3' => 'Audio',
            'pdf' => 'PDF',
            default => 'Image',
        };

        $mediaObject = new Media();
        $mediaObject
            ->setName($uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName())
            ->setType($type)
        ;

        $mediaObject->file = $uploadedFile;

        return $mediaObject;
    }
}

vich_uploader.yaml:
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    metadata:
        type: attribute
    mappings:
        media_object:
            uri_prefix: /media
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/media'
            # Will rename uploaded files using a uniqueid as a prefix.
            namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\SmartUniqueNamer
            inject_on_load: false
            delete_on_update: true
            delete_on_remove: true

